# How do I get a custom thumb image on a SeekBar in Android to be the right height?

Tags: android, seekbar

I have a layout in Android which contains a SeekBar element. Both the height and width of the SeekBar are set as "fill_parent". The parent has a layout_weight, and changes size depending on the size of the screen on which it is displayed.

The problem I'm having is that I need to use a custom graphic as the thumb image on the SeekBar, but the image won't scale to match the SeekBar size. Sometimes it is too small, and other times too big. I tried adding android:scaleType="fitXY" to the SeekBar, but this didn't help. I also tried wrapping the thumb image in a ScaleDrawable, but this didn't work either.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Comment: screenshots might help here to explain. Same for posting your layout xml.